# Document Oriented DB for AIR?

Tags: database, air, embedded-database, key-value-store, document-oriented-db

Today I just learned that Adobe Air has a local SQL database, which is great; however, we had been creating XML and JSON files to handle mostly everything. Rather than re-architect our application to gain a few new features, it would seem useful to simply index our existing data files, using an embedded document-oriented DB.

So the question is: what’s the easiest way to get an embedded documented-oriented DB running in the Adobe Air runtime?

Comment: do you need something out of the DB w/r/t indexing? does it prevent you from just using the SQL store for key/value data into which you then store the XML or JSON bits?

Comment: It is possible to just store the XML/JSON into SQL i suppose, (if i am understanding correctly). But yes it would be nice to index certain "fields" within the XML/JSON files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the DB as a key/value store. Then, if you need to index a field, add a corresponding field in your key/value table and store a (very denormalized) copy of the data in there.

I think the local DB that Air uses is SQLite -- if so, you can install triggers to keep your denormalized indexed fields synchronized.

I've done the key/value thing before to store serialized JSON trees. Not nearly as good as using CouchDB, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

guess what there is finally a [document oriented database for adobe air](https://github.com/thejustinwalsh/airejdb) through native extensions